# Why I'm getting that I have a strings while I'm working with integers?

Tags: python

Hello guys I'm new to python and I'm trying to solve this exercise
where I have a student IDs and their score in a file and I should make the dictionary whose keys are the ID and values are grade and then print the frequency of the grades (ex: A:7 etc..)
score and grade mappings are as follows: -- 90 - 100 : A -- 80 - 89 : B -- 70 - 79 : C -- 60 - 69 : D -- 0 - 59 : E
I'm working with integers only but I'm still getting the error ('>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int')so what's wrong with my code?

```
from collections import defaultdict
gradedict = {}
with open("scorelist.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
      (id, score) = line.split()
      gradedict[int(id)] = int(score)
for id,score in gradedict.items():
  if val>=90:
    print(id,score,"A")
  elif 80<score<89:
    print(id,score,"B")
  elif 70<score<79:
    print(id,score,"C")
  elif 60<val<69:
    print(id,score,"D")
  elif 0<score<59:
    print(id,score,"E")
print(gradedict)
frequency = {}
for grade in ['A','B','C','D','E']:
  frequency[grade] = ['A','B','C','D','E'].count(grade)
print(frequency)
```

and here is the inside of the file

```
121787 74
121367 71
121817 88
121619 85
131445 80
131244 96
131872 98
131963 75
131172 78
131965 72
131112 90
131956 87
141105 61
141703 61
141407 78
141569 82
141585 89
141455 82
141370 80
141837 67
141857 86
141497 94
141853 67
141245 80
151452 83
151238 62
151827 58
151409 40
151789 95
151742 71
151133 40
151095 49
151186 75
151586 51
151926 73
151975 96
151079 49
151091 100
151588 49
151630 61
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It appears that you believe that the `val` in this code should be an integer - did I understand it correctly? If so: **why**? What part of the code is supposed to make that happen? (Hint: look closely at the line `gradedict[int(key)] = val`. Notice how there is code intended to make sure that an integer is used for key that is being added to the dict? Maybe it would be a good idea to do the same thing for the value?)

Comment: I tried to do gradedict[int(val)] before posting it didn't work as well as gradedict[int(key)] = int(val)

Comment: Well, yes; that would mean to convert the `val` to an integer *and then use it as the key*. You still want to use it as the value. But there is another problem: think carefully about `for id,score in gradedict.items():`. What do you think is the purpose of the `id, score` part of this line? *What does this tell you* about how to write the code inside the loop?

Comment: Look at `id` and `score` and ask yourself 'why am I not using these?'.

Comment: Can you tell me how to implement what you're saying because I tried different ways to do it and it didn't work

Comment: Please read [ask] and keep in mind that this is not a [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) service. You are [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to try to figure out simple problems before posting, because that helps with identifying a *single, clear, specific* question that represents what you *actually* need to know. "I tried different ways to do it and it didn't work" is not answerable.

Comment: I know it's not a debugging service but maybe you don't remember yourself when you first started to learn coding.. what's simple to you is a struggle for beginners I already tried various ways to solve it but I couldn't and that's why stack overflow exist your opinion about the difficulty of my problem doesn't matter if I'm unable to understand it.

Comment: The code in your question does not produce the error you report; please see [mcve].

Comment: Can you try again now?

Comment: Where does this val came from?Isn't it score instead of val?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check if this is working,replace val with score

```
 from collections import defaultdict
    ...: gradedict = {}
    ...: try:
    ...:   with open("scorelist.txt") as f:
    ...:     for line in f:
    ...:       (id, score) = line.split()
    ...:       gradedict[int(id)] = int(score)
    ...: except:
    ...:     pass
    ...: for id,score in gradedict.items():
    ...:   if score>=90:
    ...:     print(id,score,"A")
    ...:   elif 80<score<89:
    ...:     print(id,score,"B")
    ...:   elif 70<score<79:
    ...:     print(id,score,"C")
    ...:   elif 60<score<69:
    ...:     print(id,score,"D")
    ...:   elif 0<score<59:
    ...:     print(id,score,"E")
    ...: print(gradedict)
    ...: frequency = {}
    ...: for grade in ['A','B','C','D','E']:
    ...:   frequency[grade] = ['A','B','C','D','E'].count(grade)
```

Comment: It's working thanks! I think I should do some research about try, except, pass because my nothing else has changed

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify that `val` is an integer:

```
gradedict[int(key)] = int(val)
```

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs in line #5:

```py
with open("scorelist.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split()
```

In very simple terms, `split()` is basically a *string* method. So, when you do `line.split()`, "line" is considered as a *string*, and the **split()** function then separates the string into multiple parts based on the default separator, whitespace (or just a space). These separated components (which are still strings) get assigned to **key** and **val**.
In your **scorelist.txt** document, each line is considered a string, because each line contains a *whitespace*.

To resolve this, you can modify your code and specify that you want the integer form of **val**, since **val** still contains a *string* (even though that string is *numeric*).

```py
 for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split()
       gradedict[int(key)] = int(val)
```

What's interesting is that you've already done this for **key** in your code, but you perhaps forgot to convert **val** into an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the usage of line.split() but the problem still on line 8 it's still not on my computer

Comment: unfortunately since you've changed the original code in your question, I'm unable to follow what you're saying...
but I think the main issue was "comparing str to int" is not allowed, which got fixed by using "int" before val (or "score")...
Also, based on other comments here, there's was probably a mismatch between the variables that you used for total marks, because of frequent edits... :)

Comment: Yeah you are right it's my fault but I noticed that I'm using key, val in some places and id, score in other places and that's what I've changed in my code but any way the problem is solved thanks for your time appreciated!